# objc_getProtocol() returns NULL for `NSApplicationDelegate"?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, protocols, objective-c-runtime, nsapplication

I'm trying to use the `objc_getProtocol()` function to get a reference to the struct representing the `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol:

```
Protocol *protocol = objc_getProtocol("NSApplicationDelegate");
```

However, for some reason, this always returns `NULL`.

Other protocols such as `NSObject`, `NSCoding`, `NSTableViewDelegate`, and `NSTableViewDataSource` work fine.

Is there something special about `NSApplicationDelegate`, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is it mac application? If it is then pls add that tag!

coz I dont find NSApplicationDelegate in iOS(here we hv UIApplicationDelegate) Application.!? Pls correct me if i m wrong.!

Comment: Yes, it is a Mac application (hence the AppKit tag).

Comment: You can use `@protocol(NSApplicationDelegate)` to get that.

Comment: And what about _NSApplicationLightLaunchDelegate?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use objc_getProtocol(), since I don't actually know the protocol name until runtime (I was just hard-coding the string in the example).

Comment: Of course, I could use this as a workaround...thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What happens if you call `objc_copyProtocolList()` to get a list of all protocols known to the runtime?

Comment: @fbernado - yes, _NSApplicationLightLaunchDelegate works.

Comment: @RobKeniger - I get a list of 177 protocols, but (for whatever reason) NSApplicationDelegate is not one of them. _NSApplicationLightLaunchDelegate is included in the list.

Comment: That *is* weird. Apple must be doing some sort of protocol-swizzling (which I didn't even think was possible) to have the `_NSApplicationLightLaunchDelegate` protocol masquerade as `NSApplicationDelegate`. It's odd, because `NSApplication.h` explicitly declares the protocol so it should be there. I hope you find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in the Apple docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15

The compiler creates a protocol object for each protocol declaration it encounters, but only if the protocol is also:

- Adopted by a class,
- Or referred to somewhere in source code (using
  @protocol())