# objc_getProtocol() returns NULL for `NSApplicationDelegate"?, part 2

Tags: cocoa, runtime, protocols

I, too, am trying to:

```
Protocol *protocol = objc_getProtocol("NSApplicationDelegate");
```

as seen here:

[objc_getProtocol() returns NULL for `NSApplicationDelegate"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212119/objc-getprotocol-returns-null-for-nsapplicationdelegate)

The accepted answer says that it is returning NULL because I haven't done one of:

- Adopted by a class,
- Or referred to somewhere in source code (using `@protocol()`)

Now, `@protocol` is out of question because I run this at runtime, right? So that leaves me with adding the protocol to the class, with `BOOL class_addProtocol(Class cls, Protocol *protocol)`

But how can I add a protocol to a class when the protocol was not yet created?

In other words, it seems I have to do:

```
Protocol *protocol = objc_getProtocol("NSApplicationDelegate");
BOOL class_addProtocol(class, protocol);
```

But the first line returns NULL...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your best bet at the moment is to parse the BridgeSupport files and get the method types you want from the `<informal_protocol>` tag.

NSApplicationDelegate is described in AppKit.bridgesupport:

```
<informal_protocol name='NSApplicationDelegate'>
<method selector='application:didDecodeRestorableState:' type='v16@0:4@8@12' type64='v32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:' type='v16@0:4@8@12' type64='v32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:' type='v16@0:4@8@12' type64='v32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:' type='v16@0:4@8@12' type64='v32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:openFile:' type='B16@0:4@8@12' type64='B32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:openFileWithoutUI:' type='B16@0:4@8@12' type64='B32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:openFiles:' type='v16@0:4@8@12' type64='v32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:openTempFile:' type='B16@0:4@8@12' type64='B32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:printFile:' type='B16@0:4@8@12' type64='B32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:printFiles:withSettings:showPrintPanels:' type='I24@0:4@8@12@16B20' type64='Q44@0:8@16@24@32B40'/>
<method selector='application:willEncodeRestorableState:' type='v16@0:4@8@12' type64='v32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='application:willPresentError:' type='@16@0:4@8@12' type64='@32@0:8@16@24'/>
<method selector='applicationDidBecomeActive:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationDidChangeOcclusionState:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationDidChangeScreenParameters:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationDidFinishLaunching:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationDidHide:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationDidResignActive:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationDidUnhide:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationDidUpdate:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationDockMenu:' type='@12@0:4@8' type64='@24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationOpenUntitledFile:' type='B12@0:4@8' type64='B24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:' type='B16@0:4@8B12' type64='B28@0:8@16B24'/>
<method selector='applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:' type='B12@0:4@8' type64='B24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationShouldTerminate:' type='I12@0:4@8' type64='Q24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:' type='B12@0:4@8' type64='B24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationWillBecomeActive:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationWillFinishLaunching:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationWillHide:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationWillResignActive:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationWillTerminate:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationWillUnhide:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
<method selector='applicationWillUpdate:' type='v12@0:4@8' type64='v24@0:8@16'/>
</informal_protocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this "part 2" question is the same as the answer to your original question. [The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15) says:

> Protocols that are declared but not used (except for type checking as
>   described below) aren’t represented by protocol objects at runtime.

You can't get the `Protocol` because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Just a second - I would like to know, at runtime, what methods a protocol specifies. Are you saying that for `NSApplicationDelegate` this is not possible?

Comment: Btw, I can get `objc_getProtocol("NSTextViewDelegate");` even when I didn't create any textviews...?

Comment: If `NSApplicationDeletegate` is never used anywhere in the code, then not `Protocol` object is made for it. Write a class that implements the protocol, like `@interface MyAppDelegate<NSApplicationDelegate>` and the `Protocol` object will be made.